# How to pull the value from one div into another?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to achieve something that should be fairly simple, but it doesn't work.

There are 2 divs one one page and I want to pull the value from one into another on a link click.

Here is jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SdWSs/2/

Here is the body code:

```
<div id="divone">ValueOne</div>
<input id="two">DIV two</div>
<a onclick="pullthevalue()" href="javascript:void(0);">Pull</a>
```

Function

```
function pullthevalue(){
var textValue = $('#divone').text();
$('#two').text(textValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$('#two').text(textValue)` to `$('#two').val(textValue);`

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SdWSs/3/

**Update** JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SdWSs/5/

Changed `<input id="two">DIV two</div>` to `<div id="two">DIV two</div>` so `.text(textvalue`) will work

Comment: No problem, the reason for using val instead of text is because you are trying to put in a value to an input box. if you were trying to put it into a div then .text(text) would've worked

Comment: Use the updated jsfiddle instead then your css will work aswell

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use `onclick` events tied to attributes, it's a deprecated method. Instead bind events to the DOM using jquerys `.on` or `.click` methods on the element.

You can achieve exactly what you want using either of these methods.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a').click(function(e)
    {
        var value = $('#divone').text();

        $('#two').text(value);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Alternative method using `.on`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e)
    {
        var value = $('#divone').text();

        $('#two').text(value);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: There is one particular link among 20-30 of them on the page that would be used for this cause. Should I label this particular link somehow and then activate the function like this or?

Comment: Sure, in the first function you would change the jQuery selector to point to your specific `<a>` tag `$('#myLink').click()` for example. In the second example, you would change where it says `'a'` to the selector expression instead. Then as long as this function is included on the page it will apply the event to the matching selector whenever it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try changing text() to innerHTML()... that should work. Also, the a tag can just have the href as javascript:pullthevalue() and you can take the onclick off.

Comment: It might have also not worked because the onclick doesn't have a semicolon... not sure though.